# Python string replace for UTF-16-LE file

Tags: python, string

Python 2.6

Using Python string.replace() seems not working for UTF-16-LE file. I think of 2 ways:

1. Find a Python module that can handle Unicode string manipulate.
2. Convert the target Unicode file to ASCII, use string.replace(), then convert it back. But I am worry about this may cause loss data.

Can the community suggest me a good way to solve this? Thanks.

EDIT:
My code looks like this:

```
infile = open(inputfilename)
for s in infile:
 outfile.write(s.replace(targetText, replaceText))
```

Looks like the for loop can parse the line correct. Did I make any mistakes here?

**EDIT2:**

I've read the Python Unicode tutorial and tried below code, and get it worked. However, just wondering if there's any better way to do this. Can anyone help? Thanks.

```
infile = codecs.open(infilename,'r', encoding='utf-16-le')

newlines = []
for line in infile:
    newlines.append(line.replace(originalText,replacementText))

outfile = codecs.open(outfilename, 'w', encoding='utf-16-le')
outfile.writelines(newlines)
```

Do I need to close infile or outfile?

Comment: What do you mean, it doesn't work? It does work, so if it's not working for your data, could you please provide that data on which it's not working so that we can help?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't have a Unicode file. There is no such thing (unless you are the author of NotePad, which conflates "Unicode" and "UTF-16LE").

Please read the [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html) and [Joel on Unicode](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

**Update** I'm glad the suggested reading helped you. Here's a better version of your code:

```
infile = codecs.open(infilename,'r', encoding='utf-16-le')
outfile = codecs.open(outfilename, 'w', encoding='utf-16-le')
for line in infile:
    fixed_line = line.replace(originalText,replacementText)
    # no need to save up all the output lines in a list
    outfile.write(fixed_line)
infile.close()
outfile.close()
```

It's always a good habit to release resources (e.g. close files) immediately when you are finished with them. More importantly, with output files, the directory is usually not updated until you close the file.

Read up on the "with" statement to find out about even better practice with file handling.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3

Looks like Python 3.6 will assume your file is UTF-8 by default if you open it in text mode (default):

```
>>> open('/etc/hosts')
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='/etc/hosts' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>
```

A function like `file.readlines()` will return str objects and in Python 3 strings are unicode. If you open the file in binary mode, it will be almost like Python 2 behavior:

```
>>> open('/etc/hosts', 'rb)
<_io.BufferedReader name='/etc/hosts'>
```

In this case `readlines` will return `bytes` objects and you must decode in order to get unicode:

```
>>> type(open('/etc/hosts', 'rb').readline())
bytes

>>> type(open('/etc/hosts', 'rb').readline().decode('utf-8'))
str
```

You can open your file using another encoding using the `encoding` argument:

```
>>> open('/etc/hosts', encoding='ascii')
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='/etc/hosts' mode='r' encoding='ascii'>
```

## Python 2 (this is a very old answer)

Python 2 does not care about encoding, a file is just a stream of bytes. A function like file.readlines() will return `str` objects, not `unicode` even if you open the file in text mode. You can convert each line to an unicode object using str.decode('your-file-encoding').

```
>>> f = open('/etc/issue')
>>> l = f.readline()
>>> l
'Ubuntu 10.04.1 LTS \\n \\l\n'
>>> type(l)
<type 'str'>
>>> u = l.decode('utf-8')
>>> type(u)
<type 'unicode'>
```

You can get results similar to Python 3 using `codecs.open` instead of just `open`.